# SCN Nodes bouncing

Tags: swift, 3d, nodes, scenekit, arkit

Scenekit geometry nodes bouncing after collision. Restitution is 0.0 and damping to 0.9 and have mass 1 and I have also set friction and rolling friction to max but still getting this behaviour.

````
let physicsBody2: SCNPhysicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic,

                                                                      shape: SCNPhysicsShape(node: childNode, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron,SCNPhysicsShape.Option.scale : SCNVector3(childNode.scale.x,childNode.scale.y,childNode.scale.z)]))

                    physicsBody2.damping = 0.95

                    physicsBody2.isAffectedByGravity = true

                    physicsBody2.mass = 1

                    physicsBody2.contactTestBitMask = 1

                    physicsBody2.collisionBitMask = 1

                    physicsBody2.friction = 1.0

                    physicsBody2.rollingFriction = 1.0

                    physicsBody2.restitution = 0.0

                    childNode.physicsBody = physicsBody2```
````

Link to Gif:
https://imageup.me/ga8?

I have set restitution to zero.0

> And damping to 0.9 gravity to (0,-1,0) but still this is the issue

Answer (score 1):

I observed such issues, when I had kind of a static physics floor, that was way too big. Try to make your floor smaller, like 5x5 meter plane max. In addition make your physics floor a concavePolyhedron, and not the dynamic body. concavePolyhedron has no effect on the dynamic body (leave the defaults).